# Simulating click event inside JavaScript OnClick results in error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a context menu with some options using `<li>` tags as shown below. I need to simulate click event on another ID (image), When i choose and click on this option from context menu.. I can only have the function instantaneous execution inside onclick as shown in below code-

**Edited the code to give more clarity**

```
var functionMain = function ContextMenu$functionMain(items, targetId) {
    $(menu).html(buildItems(items, targetId));
};

var buildItems = function ContextMenu$buildItems(items, targetId) {
    var i, result;
    result = '';
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        var reportId = targetId.substring(targetId.indexOf(':') + 1);
        var reportIdFormed = $('#' + reportId + 'run' + runReportLinkName);
        result += '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="text-decoration:none" onclick="(function(){'+ reportIdFormed+'.trigger(\'click\'); })();"> Run HTML </a></li>';
    }
    return result;
};
```

Above code is resulting in **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

Resultant HTML --> `<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="text-decoration:none" onclick="(function(){[object Object].trigger('click'); })();">Run HTML</a>`

How to get rid of this issue?

Comment: `reportIdFormed` is a jQuery object.

Comment: Because `reportIdFormed` is a jQuery object, if you meant for your code to end up resulting in `reportIdFormed.trigger(...)` use the actual text reportIdFormed

Comment: Why do you need the function in the `onclick` attribute?

Comment: why not using `onclick=checkEvent(this);` and then write a function `checkEvent()`.Something like that

Comment: @Teemu @PatrickEvans - Used `result += '><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="text-decoration:none" onclick="(function(){ reportIdFormed.trigger(\'click\'); })();">' + item.name + '</a></li>'; `It results in Uncaught ReferenceError: reportIdFormed is not defined

Comment: @Xufox, AlivetoDie - I can have the function outside too. Just thought it is easy to include inside onclick as it is a single line code.. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a delegated event

```
var reportId = targetId.substring(targetId.indexOf(':') + 1); 
var reportIdFormed = $('#' + reportId + 'run' + runReportLinkName);

result += '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="text-decoration:none" class="delegated-event"> Run HTML </a></li>';//add a class 

$('body').on('click','.delegated-event',function(){ //delegate the event based on that class
   reportIdFormed.trigger('click');
})
```

if the selector changes for each element then you need a attribute to store the selector:

```
var reportIdFormed = '#' + reportId + 'run' + runReportLinkName;//make it a string

    result += '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="text-decoration:none" class="delegated-event" data-selector="'+reportIdFormed+'"> Run HTML </a></li>';//add a class 

$('body').on('click','.delegated-event',function(){ //delegate the event based on that class
       reportIdFormed = $($(this).attr('data-selector'));//get the selector
       reportIdFormed.trigger('click');
    })
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks @madalinivascu - It worked. I am doing some testing and will mark this as answer in few..

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to pass and object referent instead and ID string, so you are printing that, so JS cannot print and JS object, so it will print the reference [object Object] so you should do it like so:

```
var reportId = targetId.substring(targetId.indexOf(':') + 1); //e.g. rpt1234
var reportIdFormed = '#' + reportId + 'run' + runReportLinkName; //e.g. rpt1234runHTML
result += '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="text-decoration:none" onclick="handleTrigger(reportIdFormed)"> Run HTML </a></li>';
```

Your code JS

```
function handleTrigger(id) {
 var target = $(id);
 if (target.length) {
   target.trigger("click")
 }
}
```

Comment: Edited the code - I am using OO style of JS. Changed the code that way and is giving handleTrigger undefined..

Comment: you should put the function inside an window.load or if you are using jquery use $(document).ready

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var reportId = targetId.substring(targetId.indexOf(':') + 1); //e.g. rpt1234
var reportIdFormed = reportId + 'run' + runReportLinkName; //e.g. rpt1234runHTML
result += '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="text-decoration:none" onclick="(function(){document.getElementById(\''+ reportIdFormed+'\').trigger(\'click\'); })();"> Run HTML </a></li>';
```

Comment: Got Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).trigger is not a function

Changed to onclick="(function(){document.getElementById(\''+ reportIdFormed+'\').click; })(); and it is also not fruitful --> Cannot read property 'click' of null, though that reportFormed is available in DOM giving that error.. will see what is causing that issue